Laravel Backpack LIKE query doesn't return any results
I am using laravel backpack 4 and I am facing a quite unusual situation.
I am trying to search for values ​​using the like property, so I wrote this code in the setupListOperation method:
$this->crud->addClause('where', function ($query) use ($cat, $intranet) {
    $search = request('search');

    $query->where('categoria', "news")
        ->where('is_intranet', $intranet);

    if (isset($search) && isset($search['value'])) {
        $searchTerm = $search['value'];
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($searchTerm) {
            $q->where('titolo', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%")
                ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%");
        });

        // dd($query->toSql(), $query->getBindings());
    }
});

The final query printed from the dump is as follows:
"select * from `contents` where `categoria` = ? and `is_intranet` = ? and (`titolo` LIKE '%ottobre%' or `id` LIKE '%ottobre%')"

array:2 [
  0 => "news"
  1 => "0"
]

Now if I paste the query directly in phpmyadmin I can see 3 results:
select * from `contents` where `categoria` = "news" and `is_intranet` = "0" and (`titolo` LIKE "%ottobre%" or `id` LIKE "%ottobre%") LIMIT 100

In laravel instead I doesn't get any results.
Can anyone see what's wrong here?
Thanks.

Did you try with "is_intranet" as an integer?
or you can get the real query of eloquent like this to compare
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());

Cheers.

Yes I tried with an integer and got the same result. Also if I enable the getQueryLog I get an empty array.
